# Add custom php database code above <head>

Tags: php, database

I have a non plugin script that has it's own database and I want to use it with Wordpress. How can I add custom php code that connects to this separate database in my wordpress pages? It needs to go at the top of each page above `<html>`

I am using Genesis Framework.

## Any help is appreciated.

Here is the custom function I have in my functions.php file

```
    /** Activate IP Timer Countdown */
add_action( 'init', 'your_script_function' );

function your_script_function() {

$notimeleft_str = "There is no time left";
$hours          = 48;
$minutes        = 0;
$days           = 0;
$months         = 0;
$db_host        = "localhost";
$db_user        = "xxxxx";
$db_pass        = "xxxxx";
$db_dbname      = "xxxxx";
$str = "+" . $months . ' months +' . $days . ' days +' . $hours . ' hours +' . $minutes . ' minutes';

// DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE!
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
include_once("mysql.class.php");
$db = new MySQL(true, $db_dbname, $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
$db->ThrowExceptions = true;

$script_name = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$cookie_expire = 60*60*24*365*20;

$str_interval = "+" . $months . ' months +' . $days . ' days +' . $hours . ' hours +' . $minutes . ' minutes';

if($_COOKIE['cd_until']) $cookie = json_decode($_COOKIE['cd_until'], true);
else $cookie = Array();

if(isset($_GET["reset"])) {
    //$db->DeleteRows("cd_until", Array("ip" => '"' . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . '"', "page" => '"' . $script_name . '"'));
    unset($cookie[$script_name]);
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
}
else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cd_until WHERE ip='" . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . "' AND page='" . $script_name . "'";
    $value = $db->QuerySingleRow($query);
    if($value) {
        $thedatetime = new DateTime();
        $thedatetime->setTimestamp(intval($value->until));

        $cookie[$script_name] = intval($value->until);
    } else {
        if($cookie[$script_name]) {
            $thedatetime = new DateTime();
            $thedatetime->setTimestamp( intval( $cookie[$script_name] ) );
        } else {
            $thedatetime = new DateTime();
            $thedatetime->modify( $str_interval );

            $cookie[$script_name] = intval( $thedatetime->format("U") );
        }

        $new_id = $db->InsertRow(
                "cd_until",
                Array(
                        "ip" => '"' . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . '"',
                        "until" => intval( $thedatetime->format("U") ),
                        "page" => '"' . $script_name . '"'
                )
        );
    }
}

setcookie("cd_until", json_encode($cookie), time() + $cookie_expire, "/");

}
```

Comment: OK thnaks, I added above. Let me know your thoughts - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a WordPress action hook. For example, you could add the following code to your themes functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'your_script_function' );

function your_script_function() {
    // your script here
}
```

The first line makes WordPress execute the 'your_script_function' function on initialization. You can add your script in that function.

Alternatively, you could add the code to a plugin. This would be easier for using/installing the script on multiple WordPress installations. It is indeed not recommended to edit the WordPress core files.

For more information about WordPress actions and hooks:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Hi,I tried this custom function option and it seems to interfere with my wordpress database - it makes the pages disappear. Any ideas? Thank you for the hlep.

Comment: The disappearing of your pages is probably because of the errors. Can you post your code? Most likely the problem is in the code you've placed in your custom function.

Comment: Hi Jasper, my code is too long. How do I post it? Thanks.

Comment: You can edit your question above.

Comment: You said it seemed to interfere with the database, which error(s) do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the wp-load.php file would be a safe place to put it, as it's included on all pages that use the WP functions.

Comment: I would not go modifying core files as you will have problems upgrading.

Comment: OK, I am using Genesis framework if that helps. Maybe I can use a custom function?